# Get updated center position of a UIView after orientation is changed iOS8

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios8, autolayout

I have a `UIView` as a child and i want to get the update value of center x and y origins when the view is transform its orientation from landscape to portrait or vice versa. I am using `Autolayout`

I have tried these two methods but the values weren't update inside this method.

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator

-(void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

Can anyone please tell me that is their any method to which executed when the orientation is changed and values are updated.

Comment: Can you not use 'viewWillLayoutSubviews' / 'viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Answer (score 1):

Following method is called after the transition. You can check inside this method.

```
func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also track position in

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
```

Or if you are using a controller :

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

This method is call every time your view is redraw,meaning that it will be called also after changing orientation. 
Also FYI, I prefer to not use this method to set any new layout, but just to get position as you requested. If you set frame in this method you can have some bad behaviour, difficult to debug ;)